# How to a make a Bootstrap button full width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, width

This is what I have right now. I can't get it to become full width

[Almost full width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaXlT.png)

This is the html. I've already tried adding .btn-block class but I get the same results as if I just used width: 100%; in the css. Maybe the problem is with the parent element?

```
<article class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="label label-success price"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span>$39</div>

            <div class="price-title">
                <h3>LOREM</h3>

                <small>Lorem Ipsum</small>
            </div>

            <div class="price-content ">
                <ul>
                    <li><h4>Item or Service # 1</h4></li>
                    <li><h4>Item or Service # 2</h4></li>
                    <li><h4>Item or Service # 3</h4></li>
                    <li><h4>Item or Service # 4</h4></li>
                    <li><h4>Item or Service # 5</h4></li>
                    <li><h4>Item or Service # 6</h4></li>
                </ul>

                <a href="#"><div class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</div></a>
            </div>
        </article>
```

And these are the styles

```
#tables{
color: white;
text-align: center;
margin: 15px 20px;}


.price{
position: relative;
top: 20px;
font-size: 30px;}

.price-content{
background-color: #E8E9EA;
color: #69696A;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 350px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
width: 100%;}

.btn{
border-radius: 0px;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
width: 100%;}
```

Comment: try adding `display: block;` to your parent `a`

Comment: No luck adding "display: block;" to the parent "a". Doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well first question...  why the heck are you nesting a div inside the `a` tag?  `<a href="#"><div class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</div></a>`.  Try this:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-success" href="#">Sign Up</a>
```

Then remove `padding-right: 50px;` from the `.price-content` selector.

Comment: You're right, I removed the div but still nothing changes

Comment: Wait... you have `padding-right: 50px;` on your `.price-content` box.  Thats why you button is not extending full-width.

Comment: Oh my god, yes that was the problem. Now, for some reason my list items are not centered, that's why I used the padding-right: 50px, any advice?

Comment: Don't know if it's the best way to do it, but I just added a "margin-right: 50px" to every "li". At least visually it gets the job done

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you are using

> padding-right:50px

in

> .price-content

Try moving moving your button outside of price-content div.

Comment: Glad it helped. And just to add on to your solution of adding padding to all of the li's you can write css selector like .price-content > li{ padding-right:50px} instead of adding inline css for all the li's